# F# parameter passing

Tags: f#, tuples, currying

I've always thought that F# had two different ways to pass arguments, curry style and tuple style.
Is this actually correct?

Isn't it simply *one style* , curry style, and arguments can either be simple values or tuples.

e.g.

```
someFunc (a,b) =
```

isn't this a function with *one* curry style argument which happens to be a tuple ?
Thus allowing me to pass tuples to this function using the pipleline operator?
(where the elements of the tuple is named)

```
(1,2) |> someFunc
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will work just fine - the difference is when you have

```
let f (a,b) = ...
let f2 a b = ...
```

then you can create a partially applied f2 easily, but for f it doesn't work quite as nicely - you have to do

```
let partial = fun t -> f (1,t)
let partial2 = f2 1
```

Comment: Yes, and isnt this simply because "f" has _one_ argument which happens to be a tuple with named elements? I mean you can do funky stuff like "somefunc a b c (d,e,f) g" and this is obviously neither pure curry or typle style, which had me beleive that F# only has curry style, where arguments simply are values or tuples .. is this the correct way to think of it?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, all F# *functions* are "curry style". When you have a definition like:

```
let someFunc (a,b) = a + b
```

You have a function that takes one argument, a tuple, which is being decomposed by *pattern matching* (yes, pattern matching is available in surprisingly sweet places like this). It is equivalent to the following definition which moves the pattern matching to the body of the function:

```
let someFunc t = 
    match t with 
    | a, b -> a + b
```

Which is also equivalent to

```
let someFunc = function
    | a, b -> a + b
```

The first version, with the pattern matching in the argument itself, is obviously preferable in this instance of simple named bindings.

Do note that [F# *methods*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483468.aspx), however, are "tuple style" (this is one of those places where F# glues into standard .NET object oriented features).