# Error: This expression was expected to have type byte [] but here has type 'a * 'b * 'c" in F#

Tags: function, f#, f#-3.0

```
   let IndexOf (searchWithin:byte[])(searchFor:byte[])(startIndex:int):(int) =
      //Function defination
   0

   //calling thisfunction using below
   let endIndex = IndexOf(data, delimiterBytes, startIndex)

   //data is type of byte[], delimiterBytes is also type of byte[] and 
   //startIndex is type of interger.
```

I am getting error like "This expression was expected to have type byte [] but here has type 'a * 'b * 'c". I don't understand what is meaning of 'a * 'b * 'c and why it is shwing error. Thanks.

Comment: you have used curried form rather than tupled form.  This is bounmd to be a duplicate

Comment: how I can used tupled form in "IndexOf" Function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your function definition is in what is called the curried form like

```
let t a b c = ...
```

which needs to be used like this:

t 1 2 3

you can either change your declaration to be in the tuple form

```
let t (a,b,c) = ...
```

or change the usage to be

```
t 1 2 3
```

which is the curried form.

For more on the differences see for example here:[F# parameter passing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392427/f-parameter-passing)

Comment: thanks .. i tried and it is working. Can you please tell me what is different between let t (a,b,c) and let t(a)(b)(c).

Comment: thanks. now it is clear. t(a)(b)(c) and t a b c both are same are different?

Comment: those two forms are the same